# Convert terms to values without losing precision (fractions)

Tags: python, decimal, precision

I have a function in python `pet_cycleind_symmNM(n, m)` which when called for the values `pet_cycleind_symmNM(5, 5)` returns a "term list"

```
[[Fraction(1, 14400), [[1, 25]]], [Fraction(1, 720), [[2, 5], [1, 15]]], [Fraction(1, 360), [[3, 5], [1, 10]]], [Fraction(1, 480), [[2, 10], [1, 5]]], [Fraction(1, 240), [[4, 5], [1, 5]]], [Fraction(1, 360), [[3, 5], [2, 5]]], [Fraction(13, 300), [[5, 5]]], [Fraction(1, 144), [[2, 8], [2, -2], [1, 9]]], [Fraction(1, 36), [[6, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [1, 6]]], [Fraction(1, 48), [[2, 11], [2, -2], [1, 3]]], [Fraction(1, 24), [[4, 5], [2, 1], [1, 3]]], [Fraction(1, 36), [[6, 1], [2, 5], [3, 3]]], [Fraction(1, 30), [[10, 1], [5, 3]]], [Fraction(1, 36), [[3, 7], [3, -2], [1, 4]]], [Fraction(1, 24), [[6, 2], [3, 1], [2, 4], [1, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 12), [[12, 1], [3, 1], [4, 2], [1, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 18), [[3, 5], [6, 1], [2, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 15), [[15, 1], [5, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 64), [[2, 12], [2, -2], [1, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 16), [[4, 5], [2, 2], [1, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 24), [[6, 2], [2, 5], [3, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 20), [[10, 2], [5, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 16), [[4, 6], [4, -2], [1, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 12), [[12, 1], [4, 2], [3, 1], [2, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 10), [[20, 1], [5, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 36), [[3, 3], [6, 2], [2, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 15), [[15, 1], [10, 1]]]]
```

each term consists of a `fractions.Fraction`, and a list of one or more variables

For example the term

```
[Fraction(1, 720), [[2, 5], [1, 15]]]
```

means `1/720 * a2**5 * a1**15`

I want to evaluate the sum of all terms in the list,where all the "variables" (a1, a2, a3, etc) are just the integer 4.

When calcalated "symbolically" the result should be `79846389608` but I'm getting `79728205394.7`

This is the code I'm using to evaluate the term list

```
def substitute(term, v):
    total = 1
    for a in term[1]:
        total *= v**a[1]
    return (term[0] * total)

def mat_count(n, m, q):
    terml = pet_cycleind_symmNM(n, m)
    total = 0
    for term in terml:
        total += substitute(term, q)

    return total

print mat_count(5, 5, 4)
```

How can I do this without losing precision?

Comment: The nub of the answer is sympy, where Fraction is replaced by rational and you can declare a1 and a2 as variables then used .sub to evaluate expressions involving them exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know this is supposed to total `79846389608`:

```
In [1]:
  from fractions import Fraction
  import itertools as it
  import operator as op
  import functools as ft
  fns = [[Fraction(1, 14400), [[1, 25]]], [Fraction(1, 720), [[2, 5], [1, 15]]], [Fraction(1, 360), [[3, 5], [1, 10]]], [Fraction(1, 480), [[2, 10], [1, 5]]], [Fraction(1, 240), [[4, 5], [1, 5]]], [Fraction(1, 360), [[3, 5], [2, 5]]], [Fraction(13, 300), [[5, 5]]], [Fraction(1, 144), [[2, 8], [2, -2], [1, 9]]], [Fraction(1, 36), [[6, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [1, 6]]], [Fraction(1, 48), [[2, 11], [2, -2], [1, 3]]], [Fraction(1, 24), [[4, 5], [2, 1], [1, 3]]], [Fraction(1, 36), [[6, 1], [2, 5], [3, 3]]], [Fraction(1, 30), [[10, 1], [5, 3]]], [Fraction(1, 36), [[3, 7], [3, -2], [1, 4]]], [Fraction(1, 24), [[6, 2], [3, 1], [2, 4], [1, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 12), [[12, 1], [3, 1], [4, 2], [1, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 18), [[3, 5], [6, 1], [2, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 15), [[15, 1], [5, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 64), [[2, 12], [2, -2], [1, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 16), [[4, 5], [2, 2], [1, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 24), [[6, 2], [2, 5], [3, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 20), [[10, 2], [5, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 16), [[4, 6], [4, -2], [1, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 12), [[12, 1], [4, 2], [3, 1], [2, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 10), [[20, 1], [5, 1]]], [Fraction(1, 36), [[3, 3], [6, 2], [2, 2]]], [Fraction(1, 15), [[15, 1], [10, 1]]]]
In [2]:
  sum(x*ft.reduce(op.mul, (a**b[1] for a, b in zip(it.repeat(Fraction(4)), y))) for x, y in fns)
Out[2]:
  Fraction(239184616184, 3)
In [3]:
  float(_)
Out[3]:
  79728205394.66667
```

Comment: I believe I know because the original code is written in maple, and it has the same "termlist".  maple does symbolic manipulation with "real" precision.  It's only at this final evaluation stage that the results come out different.  Also it works for smaller inputs

Comment: actually, It seems I have a bug, because I see a negative exponent which should not be.  Thanks.  Your way of evaluating the fraction at the end was pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates how to process a single term containing both `a1` and `a2` using sympy.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> def evaluate(term):
...     frac, a1a2 = term
...     a2_val,a1_val = a1a2
...     return 'Rational({},{})+a2**{}+a1**{}' . format(frac.numerator,frac.denominator,a2_val[1],a1_val[1])
... 
>>> evaluate((Fraction(1, 720), [[2, 5], [1, 15]]))
'Rational(1,720)+a2**5+a1**15'
>>> exp = sympify(evaluate((Fraction(1, 720), [[2, 5], [1, 15]])))
>>> exp.subs(a2,4).subs(a1,4)
773094850561/720
```